# RxJava Scheduler.Worker schedule Action that subscribes to an Observable

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I schedule an `Action0` that triggers a function that I want to subscribe to. Currently I can't think of a better way to do this beyond calling `toBlocking().single()`. What's more, I also want to schedule the `Action0` again after it has completed.

There must be a more idiomatic way of doing this. Do I also leave myself open to memory leaks by not handling the `Subscription` returned by the `.schedule()`?

```
worker.schedule(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            try {
                consumer.doSomething().toBlocking().single();
            } finally {
                worker.schedule(this);
            }
        }
});
```

FWIW I'm stuck with RxJava 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RxJava world, you probably don't want to use the explicit `schedule()` operations.

A better way to accomplish what your describe would be:

```
Observable.fromCallable( consumer.doSomething() )
  .repeat()
  .subscribeOn( scheduler )
  .subscribe();
```

This will invoke `doSomething()` over and over again, ignoring the output. The `repeat` operator will resubscribe when the call is done.

Comment: Ok, I like this! Given that consumer returns an observable itself, what if I just put a `.repeat` on `consumer.doSomething()` directly?

Comment: Yes: add the `repeat` operator to `consumer.doSomething()` directly.

Comment: And how about if I wanted schedule it to run periodically. ie: `worker.schedule(initialDelayMillis, periodMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: Use `Observable.interval( initialDelayMillis, periodMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )` as the first step, and `flatMap()` to introduce `consumer.doSomething()` into the chain.